# Full width header won't work

Tags: html, css, background, header, size

I am trying to make a full width (100%) header in black on the top of my page, the problem is that there is a border around it, which isn't blackwhat am I doing wrong?

This is my code (html):

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainColorTest.css" />
    <title>Home Color Test</title>

    <div id="header">
    </div>

</head>
```

This is my code (css):

```
body {
    background-color: #ffbc36;
    background-image: url('BackgroundWhiteMid.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000000;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You have the `<div id="#header">` in the `<head>` element. Is it only on StackOverflow or also like that in your html?

Comment: it's also like that in my html

Comment: It should be under the `<body>` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style :

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Browsers usually add margin to the body, so that the content is not stuck at the borders. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqa3kc2d/) of your example.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a margin on your body,

try adding

```
margin: 0px;
```

to

```
body {
 margin: 0px;
 ...
}
```

Most browsers have some default css values on body and other tags.
You can avoid encountering problems with this kind of behavior in the future by using a css reset.

e.g.
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

The body (and some other html elements) has default margin. That is the reason of the border.